# In-App Plugin possible with MVVMCross

Tags: android, ios, windows-store-apps, add-in, mvvmcross

I am planning to use MVVMCross for an app that shall be runnable on iOS and Android tablets.
As I saw the plugin-architecture of MVVMCross I was wondering if it would be possible to build in-app plugins. (I fear this is not the correct name)

What I mean is: 
My application App1 is shipped as a standalone product.
Now what I want to do is to develop several add-ins that people can purchase in order to improve their app.

I already saw, that developing add-ins is possible for android, but I could not quite find out how to do it with Xamarin.

1) Can you write "in-app plugins" for
    a) iOS apps
    b) android apps
    c) windows store apps
    ...that are distributed via
    x) the playstore/appstore/windows store
    y) or via a company-wide distribution mechanism (such as testflight uses it)?

2) Can the plugin-architecture of MVVMCross be extended to support something like that?
   Maybe this is not the correct way and one should add some kind of "add-in" support to MVVMCross?

Please help me - I'm quite confused. I am also willing to contribute to MVVMCross. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically downloading code into store apps is not generally supported in most app stores so this approach probably won't work if the plugins include code/functionality.

You can, however, download content and you can use in-app payments to enable features.

I can't comment on the TestFlight distribution mechanism - I don't know how that works.